# Reading variables while debugging with GDB (C)

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am  beginner with GDB debbuging. I need read variables in GDB, I use the command info variable and get this information:

```
 0x000007c4 variable1.0
 0x000007c8 variable2.1
```

I set a breakpoint inside the variables function and these are defined how type long *. How can I read the value inside these correctly? I tried with show, display, print $variable1, p/x variable and so on commands.

Sorry for my grammar, i am not native speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view the contents of memory use gdb's **x/FMT ADDRESS** command e.g. **x/d 0x000007c4** (to display an integer sized object from address 0x000007c4 and format it in decimal).

The **info variables** command in gdb will list all global and static variables and their program addresses. You don't describe the language or implementation you're using, but in C the variable name "variable1.0" is not valid. Therefore it must have been created by some link editor or the compiler in a post-process. Therefore the symbol may not exist in debug information and is only accessible by directly viewing the contents of memory, which is why the gdb **p** command doesn't work (there is no valid expression to show you that variable because it's not a variable, but just a symbol at an address).

Comment: i used dynamic reservation, and I forgot to metion but I put the c tag.